# Editing php files through another php file

Tags: php, database

I'm working at a project right now, which is a very simple database-application. There are some php files which the user should upload. Then he calls a specific file - let it be `install.html`, where he should enter his root and password for accessing the server. Then a database and some tables will be created. Now, there are other files, for which this information is also needed. I thought about including a `connect.php`. But here's the question: Is it possible to edit the root and password in this `connect.php` through another php file? If not, do you know any other user-friendly way of avoiding this problem?

Comment: Depends on what is in the file.  Can you post any code?

Comment: You mean allowing users to upload and/or change PHP scripts? Your server will be in great danger.

Comment: But how should i handle this probleme? Either i allow the user to change it this way, or he should change the data in the .php file on itself, which isn't really user-friendly, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can do that. The general idea is that you 've got a string with placeholders (e.g. like "{{username}}" and "{{password}}") that you replace with the correct values with `str_replace` and then write the contents to the file with `file_put_contents`.

The string with the placeholders can either be declared in your script as a string or you can read it from a file with `file_get_contents`. So you could have:

```
$replacements = array(
    '{{username}}' => 'root',
    '{{password}}' => '123456',
);
$config = file_get_contents('config.php');
$config = str_replace(array_keys($replacements),
                      array_values($replacements),
                      $config);
file_put_contents('config.php', $config);
```

Comment: This is correct, however make sure your `connect.php` has the right permissions (to be written to).

Answer (score 0):

A PHP file is just a text file. Like you can change a text-file with PHP you can also change a PHP file with PHP. Which is just standard file-io, see [Filesystem<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/filesystem).

Ensure you have got access to the file and it is readable. Also consider to educate users after they used your install script how they can harden their setup. PHP files should be read-only in a hosting environment because of security reasons.